# start multiple processes in docker container from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to start multiple processes `p1`, `p2` ... `pn` when I start docker container. I can achieve that for one process by:

```
CMD p1
```

But I want to do that for multiple processes and I want to run all processes in background. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905912/docker-container-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

You could have a start script that executes the processes.

eg 
Dockerfile

```
CMD ./start.sh

start.sh
./process-1.sh
./process-2.sh
./process-3.sh &
```

It's import to keep the parent process running otherwise docker will kill all processes and the container will stop running.(that's tripped me up before)

You could alternatively use supervisor or somethng to that effect.